# Books / lecture series on Homotopy theory

Tags: reference-request

I want to read homotopy theory on my own so I want to know prerequisites, good books and if there is any lectures available which can help me. Links are welcome.
Till now I have done point-set topology.
Thanks

Comment: See [prerequisites](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1067210/10014), [courses](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/182447/10014), [book on homotopical algebra](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/64421/10014).  My 2 cents: you're not going to get by just with point set topology. You probably should learn some algebraic topology first.